# Laravel subdomain config

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, configuration

Our staging environment on a project uses the same domain AKA staging.mydomain.com. How do I get the Laravel database config to point to a different DB as the config switch is based on the hostname which is the same for staging. and www.?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Hi Latheesan, thanks for the response. Yes I did try but landed up doing a switch case statement to handle my different environments as I started having CLI issues with your suggestion. Thanks for guiding me in the correct direction tho :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `detectEnvironment` method to use a closure function and run your login in there to determine if your application is local or not.

update **bootstrap/start.php** like this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {
    return preg_match('/staging/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? 'staging' : 'production';
});
```

Now when you are visiting your laravel project from http://staging.xxx URL, it will detect it as `staging` environment.

Now, you can place the database config specific to `staging` env in here:

**app/config/staging/database.php**

This should do the trick.